# Calculate this limit (function with square roots)

Tags: calculus, limits

\begin{aligned}\lim\limits_{x \to 7} ~ \dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{\sqrt{x-3}-2} = {{2}\over{3}}\end{aligned}

According to http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/calculus/limit-calculator.php

How?

Answer (score 4):

Try using $\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{\sqrt{x-3}-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{\sqrt{x-3}-2}\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}+3}{\sqrt{x-3}+2}\dfrac{\sqrt{x-3}+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+3}=\dfrac{x-7}{x-7}\dfrac{\sqrt{x-3}+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+3}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x-3}+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+3}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use L'hospitale rule since both the numerator and denominator goes to zero as x --> 7

Answer (score 1):

Using L'hospitale rule we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 7}\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-3}}}\\
=\lim_{x\to 7}\frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\\
=\frac{2}{3}
$$